# Flutter : agora rtc engine make the app crash in the another device

Tags: flutter, dart, agora.io

I want to add agora_rtc_engine plugin into my app , but I'm facing a problem with it . When i debugging the app on real device it is working and when i installing it on another device it doesn't work and show me that on the device screen

> agora video call flutter keep stopping

I'm using the agora quick start example https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Flutter-Quickstart

can any one know the wrong with it ?

Comment: Can you share your build logs?

Answer (score 1):

It happens to me when I rewrite code or copy lib. But when I download examples like this one https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Flutter-Quickstart everything works.

Temporary you can build your project on this one, just changing name and reinstalling it on your phone.